# My JavaScript function keeps running on every postback, how can I prevent this?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

       function OpenNav() {

            document.getElementById("dashsidenav1").style.width = "200px";
            document.getElementById("dasha1").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("openbtn").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("dasha1").style.transition = "0.8s";

       }

       function CloseNav() {

           document.getElementById("dashsidenav1").style.width = "0px";
           document.getElementById("dashsidenav1").style.transition = "0.8s";
           document.getElementById("dasha1").style.display = "none";
           document.getElementById("dasha1").style.transition = "0.8s";
           document.getElementById("openbtn").style.display = "none";
       }
    </script>

'the OpenNav() Function opens my side navigation bar on button click
<div class="dashtopnav1">
        <a href="#" onclick="openNav()" id="opnav"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></span></a>
</div>

'the ClosNav() Funtion closes my side navigation bar on button click
<a href="#" onclick="closeNav()" id="clossbtn" style="margin-left:180px; font-size:x-large; color:white;"><span>&times</span></a>
```

This works fine when I click these buttons but the problem is this script keeps running on every postback, which I don't want.

Comment: you mean it runs each time the page re-loads? And they both run? There's no code shown here which would do that. Are you calling these functions somewhere else? It's unclear.

Comment: Yes it runs each time the page reloads and am sure am not calling the function anywhere else in my code too.

Comment: Sorry but you must be. The code above wouldn't do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are not referencing these 2 functions anywhere else? Also, your function names are "CloseNav" and "OpenNav" but your onclick event references them as "closeNav" and "openNav" which should throw an error sense it's case sensitive.

Comment: Sorry I think the upper case omission was just a typo error in my code it's the same as the function name. Please any help?

Comment: @mcvision if you made a mistake in the code you showed us please [edit it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55289256/edit), so we can see what it really looks like. And then go and do a Find in your IDE to see if you can locate any other references to those function names anywhere else in your code.

Comment: OK will check and get back please thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks very much for the help. I did a thorough find through out my code and found other reference to the script. I removed that and it worked good. Thanks a lot.